# insert an image inside Li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have this html code

```
<ul id="discussion">
  <li>my name is aymen <img src="img.jpg"</li>
</ul>
<input type="button" id="send" />
<input type="text" id="message"/>
```

and this one :

```
<script>

   $('#send').click(function (){
   var mes = $('#message').val().replace('(<3)', '<img src="pics/lol/love.png">');
   $('#discussion').append('<li >' + mes+'</li>');});

</script>
```

Expactation :

message + the picture

but i found :

message +

```
 <img src="pics/lol/love.png"/>
```

Comment: Any HTML you append to an input will be treated as text. Therefore what you're trying to do is not possible.

Comment: but it works when i write Append('<li><img src="img.png" />'+mes'<li>' )

Comment: Ah yes - I misunderstood the question. I added an answer for you below.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because you have a syntax error in the `append()` call. You've closed the string before the `>` and have missed the `)` at the end. Also note that the `img` element in your HTML is missing the closing `/>`. Try this:

```js
$('#send').click(function() {
  var mes = $('#message').val().replace('(<3)', '<img src="pics/lol/love.png">');
  $('#discussion').append('<li>' + mes + '</li>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="discussion">
  <li>my name is aymen <img src="img.jpg" /></li>
</ul>
<input type="button" id="send" value="Send" />
<input type="text" id="message" value="Foo (<3)" />
```

Comment: In that case please edit your question to ckearly5state the output you're trying to acheiev

Answer (score 1):

1- The image has not closing tag. Remove the bad formed `<li>` in your html:

```
  <li>my name is aymen <img src="img.jpg"</li>
```

2- Maybe your script block is before the tag, so put your jquery code in a **document.ready** block:

```
document.ready(function(){
   $('#send').click(function() {
   var mes = $('#message').val().replace('(<3)', '<img src="pics/lol/love.png">');
   $('#discussion').append('<li>' + mes + '</li>');
   }); 
}
```

3- Change your input to this:

```
<input type="text" id="message" value="(<3)" />
```

4- Check your jquery link.